# How to offer non-consumable content for in app purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app for learning piano and I would like to offer lessons as non-consumable in app purchases. All of the files that are required for the lesson will be bundled with the app (as they don't take up a ton or space; two PDFs, a .mid, and a .png). Currently, for testing purposes, I have just been hard coding the lessons into my app and they get loaded on viewDidLoad.

My question is how can I store a library of lessons that I can modify when a purchase is made to show that it had been purchased? Essentially, all I want to do is when a completed transaction is received, the value of purchaseStatus will change from 0 to 1.

The stored data consists of a number of strings, NSNumbers, and an array of NSNumbers.

I have seen a few options such as plists and NSUserDefaults but I'd really appreciate some advice on the best way to go about it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say storing the purchase status of each purchasable module in an NSDictionary that you store in NSUserDefaults would probably be the most straightforward/simplest option. Every time you launch the app, query this dictionary to determine what has been purchased and accordingly reveal those purchased entities to the user (in the form of an entry in a table view, an icon, a no longer hidden button, etc.).

Plists are fair game as well, but it would require a bit more maintenance (where to store the plist so that it may be backed up by iCloud, etc.) whereas NSUserDefaults has that all taken care of for you (it's backed up by iCloud).

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. When it comes to updating to new versions of the app, will these changes persist or will they be reset? If they are backed up to iCloud, I would image they would persist but I may be wrong.

Comment: Whatever is stored in NSUserDefaults persists as long as the app is not deleted. So if the user removes the app at any point that data is gone. If they have the app installed and perform an update, that data will persist. This is also why it is essential to implement restore purchase logic as per the In-App Purchase Programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267

Comment: Yea, I figured I'd have to put in a restore method for fresh launches. Cool, I think that should work for me. I'll hard code the lessons in a "library" that is read into an array on first launch or after an upgrade. On first launch, I can have it set up the lessons in NSUserDefaults by iterating through the song library (checking to see if there is already an entry under the key (which will be the product ID). Then, have it check for previous purchases and flag them appropriately in the NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Otherwise, if it's the first launch after an upgrade, it can check to see if any new songs have been added to the hard coded library and then add entries into the NSUserDefaults for them. That sounds like it should work, does it not? Thanks Stunner :)